# Undefined reference to 'vtable for

Tags: c++, virtual, vtable

I think it's important to note that this compiles fine on Visual Studio 2012, but not in g++. It evened compiled fine at one point before I implemented RSA.cpp. I haven't touched the header files since. The error is:

```
cipher.o: In function `RSA_433::RSA_433()':
/home/andrew/Desktop/ciphers/RSA.h:18 undefined reference to `vtable for RSA_433'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's RSA.h:

```
class RSA_433: public CipherInterface
{

public:


    RSA_433(){}
    virtual bool setKey(const unsigned char* key);

    virtual unsigned char* encrypt(const unsigned char* plaintext);

    virtual unsigned char* decrypt(const unsigned char* ciphertext);

protected:

    RSA* RSAkey;
    const char* keyFileName;
};
```

and RSA.cpp:

```
//RSA_433::RSA_433(){}  removed

bool RSA_433::setKey(const unsigned char* key){//body}

unsigned char* RSA_433::encrypt(const unsigned char* plaintext){//body}

unsigned char* RSA_433::decrypt(const unsigned char* ciphertext){//body}
```

RSA.h also inherits from:

```
class CipherInterface
{
public:

    CipherInterface(){}

    virtual bool setKey(const unsigned char* key){ return false;  }

    virtual unsigned char* encrypt(const unsigned char* plaintext){ return NULL; }

    virtual unsigned char* decrypt(const unsigned char* ciphertext) { return NULL; }


};
```

Comment: You sure that's the whole `CipherInterface`? no missing destructor? (possibly undefined, pure?)

Comment: It sounds like you're not linking RSA.o.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore yea, that's all of it. It worked fine before..

Comment: @aschepler I linked it in my make file. It compiled before  I implemented rsa.cpp

Comment: Not sure what's going on with your installation of g++ but the code looks ok to me and it also compiles and links fine under cygwin/g++ for me.

Comment: Then it must be my implementation that's screwing it up.. Although I don't see how that's even possible.. But thank you nevertheless

Comment: `CipherInterface` should have a `virtual` destructor (or make it non-`virtual` and `protected`)

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have two definitions for `RSA_433::RSA_433()`. One in the `.h` file and one in the `.cpp` file

Also, all the methods defined in class `CipherInterface` are inline. According to [GCC standard](https://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#vtables),

> The ISO C++ Standard specifies that all virtual methods of a class
>   that are not pure-virtual must be defined, but does not require any
>   diagnostic for violations of this rule [class.virtual]/8. Based on
>   this assumption, GCC will only emit the implicitly defined
>   constructors, the assignment operator, the destructor and the virtual
>   table of a class in the translation unit that defines its first such
>   non-inline method

That means GCC will only include vftable in the object file for the translation unit where the definition of the first non-pure, and non-inline virtual member function is present. If there is no such definition, vftable will not be included for the class.

Comment: Whoops, that was added on my part to try to fix it. Forgot to take it out. Still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: You should add and implement a virtual destructor in `CipherInterface` and the problem will go away.